# How do I tell Sublime Text to highlight the Go code inside my HTML?

Tags: html, go, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, hugo

Sublime Text can highlight HTML. It can highlight Go. I would like to tell Sublime Text 3 to highlight the Go code in between the `{{` and `}}` markers in my HTML to highlight in Go rather than as plain text.

There must be some way to combine the two. I thought surely one of the golang packages on Package Control would address this but I haven't found one that offers an *HTML (Go)* syntax like GitHub's Atom editor does by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default highlighting packages will not correctly highlight your templates. You'll need to [install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and then install [GoSublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GoSublime).

Once you've done that, open your template file. Then click View > Syntax > GoSublime > GoSublime: HTML.

You should now have `{{define "foo"}}{{end}}` highlighted as Go and `<p>foo</p>` highlighted as HTML.